# Can't access data variable inside watcher, inside .map()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, array.prototype.map

My root looks like this. I have defined types and history variables inside data and in watch, I am trying to access another variable rather than the one I am watching. Trying to access history variable outside `.map()` works however using it inside `.map()` returns `undefined`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',

  data: {
     types: {},
     history: {}
  }

  watch: {
     types: {
         handler(obj) {
            console.log(this.history) // works

            types.map(function(val) {
               console.log(this.history) // undefined
            })
         }
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to use es6 syntax, try `types.map((val) => {...})` assuming you're using webpack or something to compile your JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a CDN you will need to bind `this` to your function. Try the following:

```
 types.map(function(val) {
     console.log(this.history)
 }).bind(this);
```

Comment: I tried `types.map((val) => {...}}` and it works fine. Thanks a lot!